# Printing problems with libreoffice and (remote) cups server

Tags: ubuntu, printer, network-printer, libreoffice, cups

we have cups running on an ubuntu server managing all printing jobs.
on the ubuntu clients the server is set in client.conf
Printing works from every tested program, but not from libreoffice. (tested on 4 printers)

After clicking print no error is shown but the print job is not even send to the server.
Always have to save as pdf and print from evince or acroread.

also there are no printers shown in "printer settings" option inside libreoffice.

similar problem with printers shared by cups, they are not even shown in print menu. (also tested on arch)

is there some way to log what libreoffice is doing? can't find debug/verbose option

Answer (score 0):

currently i have the same problem. not a single printjobs reaches cups. but u can exchange the printing dialog of libre.office to use the embedded system one. its a workaround and doesnt solve the real problem.

Tools>Settings>General (uncheck "Use LibreOffice dialogs" and check "Use experimental features")